# TFS 2015 set label for "Visual Studio Test" step

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfs-2015

I'm build und test solutions with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015.
For each **Nunit-Projekt** a created a **"Visual Studio Test" Step**.

If a build completed I see all test result like this:

- 1171:VSTest Test Run release x64 (The number is the `runId`)
- 1172:VSTest Test Run release x64

**Build Result:**

[image]

But I don't have a reference to which **Nunit-Projekt** these results belongs.

**Build Definition:**

[image: Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015]
(I tried the field (1) but it is doesn't affect the result)

**Question:**

Is there a way to modify these Test Result Labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "Test Run Tile" of "Visual Studio Test" step will change this:
[image]

Comment: I don't have this group "Reporting Options", I added a new screenshot.

Comment: @dh_cgn What's the version of the TFS you use? I'm using TFS2015 Update 3.

Comment: **Reporting Options** is a **new feature** which comes with TFS2015 **Update 2**!

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your task by clicking the edit button next to the task title:

[image]

Comment: I already did this, the will not changed the label of the test run.

Comment: If that didn't work I would open a bug.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues